# Querying pseudo classes of an element in pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I know I can check some pseudo classes' state with JQuery (like isHovered) and I know I can check an element has a particular pseudo class by running querySelector (/querySelectorAll) on its parent node.

The first is totally useless for me cause I'm not gonna use JQuery and JQuery doesn't have a `is` method for the pseudo class I need to query.

The second solution seems dirty, I mean if it's a property of an object (object being the Dom element) I should be able to get it in a straightforward way not by running q function on its parent node. What if my element doesn't have a parent node (you may question the possibility of an element without parent node that has pseudo classes. It may or may not be possible right now in a browser, but theoretically it's possible, maybe in a virtual Dom, or in a future implementations of browsers, idk.).

All I want is something like `element.hasPseudoClass("<the class>")` or `element.getPseudoClasses()` or any other convenient way to query pseudo classes of an element. I didn't find something straight forward.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

```
element.matches(':hover')
```

```js
var box = document.getElementById("box");
var msg = document.getElementById("msg");

setInterval(() => msg.textContent = box.matches(':hover') ? "in" : "out", 1000);
```

```html
<div id="box" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red; "></div>
<div id="msg"></div>
```

See the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/matches).

Comment: Thanks, none of threads about this issue I found on Google mentioned this solution. I knew there must be something like this.

Comment: It doesn't work on Chrome the way you written it here even. Please change it to `element.matches('div:hover')` or `element.matches(element.tagName+':hover')`

Comment: Works fine for me on Chrome 51. `:hover` is a perfectly valid selector and should not need to be qualified by a tagname.